# Why doesn't my ListView show Details view properly?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

So, I've got a list view, as indicated by the question title. I've got two columns set up: Name and Date Modified. These were added in the designer, here's the code emitted by the designer for reference:

```
// lstFiles
this.lstFiles.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
this.clmName,
this.clmDate});
// ...

// clmName
this.clmName.Text = "Name";
this.clmName.Width = 105;

// clmDate
this.clmDate.Text = "Modified";
this.clmDate.Width = 128;
```

In the designer, this looks beautiful.

The list items themselves are a tiny subclass of ListViewItem that simply extracts some metadata from a file (in this case, the date modified), and adds a sub-item to itself:

```
class GalleryItem : ListViewItem {
    public string File;
    public DateTime DateModified;

    public GalleryItem(string file) : base(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)) {
        this.ImageKey = Path.GetExtension(file);
        File = file;
        DateModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);

        this.SubItems.Add(DateModified.ToString());
    }
}
```

To add items to the list, I simply do this:

```
lstFiles.BeginUpdate();
lstFiles.Clear();

foreach (String f in files) {
    ListViewItem lvi = new GalleryItem(f);
    lvi.Group = lstFiles.Groups["grpFiles"]; //this varries

    //omitted: check/add icon to list 

    lstFiles.Items.Add(lvi);
}

lstFiles.EndUpdate();
```

So, this all works great for Large Icon view, etc:

[image: Large Icon View]

However, it breaks down on Details view:

[image: Details View]

There *are* items in the list (there's a scroll bar). If you click roughly in the column under the red arrow (added in paint), you'll select an item (the upper-right area is an image preview), but you won't see anything selected.

In summary, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did this red arrow come from?  You cannot just override OnPaint and/or mess with the UserPaint style.

Comment: Please make sure you read the whole question: "If you click roughly in the column under the **red arrow (added in paint)**"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just whipped up a sample to test this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var G1 = new ListViewGroup("Group 1");
        var G2 = new ListViewGroup("Group 2");

        Application.Run(new Form {
            Controls = {
                new ListView  {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    Groups = { G1, G2 },
                    View = View.Details,
                    //Columns = { "First", "Second" },
                    Items = {
                        new ListViewItem { Text = "One", Group = G1, SubItems = { "1" } },
                        new ListViewItem { Text = "Two", Group = G2, SubItems = { "2" } },
                        new ListViewItem { Text = "Three", Group = G2, SubItems = { "3" } },
                    },
                },
            },
        });
    }
}
```

You will notice that it duplicates the problem. If you uncomment the line that creates the columns it works. This suggests that your columns don't exist.

And while typing this the answer popped into my head:

**You are calling `ListView.Clear` instead of `ListView.Items.Clear` so you are removing the columns in code.**

Comment: Holy crap. See folks, this is why proper sleep is essential for quality code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are not able to use Groups in Details view. I can't test this right now, so I am going off straight memory. However, try populating your list without the Groups and see what happens. I strongly suspect it is the Group part that is causing the problem.

Comment: I tried removing the Groups-related code as per your suggestion, but I still get the same problem. :(

Comment: @SIVSolutions : It is possible to use Groups in Details View mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem identified by Tergiver, but there is one more gotcha - when you add the columns, the ListView must be in View.Details mode.